# add custom properties to knockout model object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am working with knockout and mvc. I make a call to an mvc controller to retrieve json that I create a model object from and apply it to a div:

```
 myModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(items);
    ko.applyBindings(myModel , document.getElementById("my-container"));
```

I am wondering how can I extend my myModel object (which is populate from json from the controller) to have custom properties based upon values on the object returned from my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would want to use the `create` callback as described in this section of the documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing_object_construction_using_create

It is also possible to simply add properties to `myModel` after creating it via the mapping plugin in your example.